# How to remove delay in Android GCM?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, google-cloud-messaging

I found that a Push Fixer app is using

```
com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT
com.google.android.intent.action.GTALK_HEARTBEAT
```

But Don't know how to use them and broadcast them in android.

Please help i am new to android...

I want to remove delay in gcm

Also want to know how to set heartbeat interval

Thanks

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2516849

Comment: i have to implement in my app can't use any app...

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I found my answer...

Comment: Please share your answer with us

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the heartbeat one has to send these broadcasts:

`context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.GTALK_HEARTBEAT"));
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT"));`

Comment: what i don't understand is that how these broadcasts fix this problem. We are not sending anything like "2 Minutes" here